# Outlook 2010 export emails to msg files

Tags: windows-7, email, microsoft-outlook-2010

In Outlook 2010 we're trying to export GDPR confirmation emails.
When selecting all emails and dragging them to a folder on the desktop, the mails stop copying at 129 items.
I was not able to find a source why Outlook or Windows behaves this way.

It's also not possible to export to msg, only to pst, xls and Access.
I did find however a lot of tools that can convert pst to msg but none of them were free.

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Dragging the messages out of Outlook into a folder creates .msg files. Have you tried this?

Comment: Yes, but they stop at 129 items.

Comment: Can you select a message in the message list, then go to File > Save as to save the mail as .msg?

Comment: @YukiSun No, only to txt

Comment: What if dragging fewer messages each time instead of "selecting all"?

Comment: @YukiSun That is an impossible task if we have more than 6000 emails. The chance that some will be forgotten is very high.

Comment: This is a free tool: https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookMessagesExportMSG

Comment: @thims This does not work in a domain environment.